# ADO.NET Data Services Query Interceptor - can anyone tell me the VB syntax of this C#?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, ado.net, code-conversion

I am pretty new to VB.NET - and I'm struggling to convert the signature of the method in the following code snippet. The Expression<...>> bit.

Thanks in advance.

```
 [QueryInterceptor("Orders")]
 public Expression<Func<Orders,bool>> OnQueryOrders()
 {
     return o => o.Customer.ContactName == 
         HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name          
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Public Function OnQueryOrders() As Expression(Of Func(Of Orders, Boolean))
```